# Implementing Notifications in an Offline Android App without relying on Server

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am new to Android development, and I'm unsure if it's possible or not. I have an Android yoga app that operates offline without relying on a server. Every weekend, I need to show my users only a few notifications sentences stored within the app. I am looking for a way to achieve this without relying on a server for implementation.

I am trying with this method, but it only works when the app is opened. and does not work when the app is closed. Is there any way for it to work even when the app is closed?

`

```
// setting up the notification 
// Set the desired date and time for the notification 

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY); 
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20); 
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); 
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// Create a new PendingIntent for the BroadcastReceiver
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
);


// Get the AlarmManager and schedule the alarm
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);`
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 



    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        // Handle the alarm trigger here, show the notification 
        showNotification(context); 
    }


    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        // Create the notification channel (if not already created)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "channel_id",
                    "Channel Name",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    
        // Create the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_id")
                .setContentTitle("Yoga App")
                .setContentText("Take a moment for yourself and unwind with a soothing yoga session in our app today")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}}`
```

I tried this method but it only worked when the app is open. Is there any way that it can work even when the app is closed?

Comment: That will depend entirely on your definition of "the app is closed". `AlarmManager` is designed for use when your process is not running, and so that part should work fine. However, there will times when your app is in a state where your alarms get cancelled, such as when the user clicks "Force Stop" in the Settings app's page for your app. Depending on the device manufacturer, other user actions may also cancel your alarms.

Comment: Thank you for your response @CommonsWare. The code I provided does not show a notification when I exit the app or when the app is closed. But when I start the app, it suddenly shows the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this method should work. I made the same feature in my project. But after comparing our approach I see a few differences. Instead `alarmManager.setExact` use `alarmManager.setRepeating` as you need this Push to repeat. **Also, there is no guarantee that Push will be sent exactly in a specific second.** It could be later. Just wait some time. Here is my working example for sending Push every weekend. Maybe you find something useful for you.

```
private void initLocalPushNotificationBroadcast() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 11100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    long time = Utils.getStartCurrentWeekInMilliseconds(1) - Utils.MILLISECONDS_IN_15_HOUR;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            time,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
            broadcast);
}


public static long getStartCurrentWeekInMilliseconds(int offsetFromCurrentWeek) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TIME_ZONE);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
    cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
    cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    // get start of this week in milliseconds
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    // start of the week
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, offsetFromCurrentWeek);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Call `initLocalPushNotificationBroadcast` in `onCreate` method in Application class.

And here is AlarmReceiver:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {

    val resultIntent = Intent(context, RankingActivity::class.java)
    resultIntent.putExtra(WEEKLY_PERFORMANCE_EVENT, true)
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.PN_RECEIVED_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis())
    val backIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, 0, arrayOf(backIntent, resultIntent), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    val builder = Notification.Builder(context)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId(channelId)
    }
    val notification = builder.setContentTitle("Weekly performance")
        .setContentText("Content.")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()

    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Weekly performance",
            IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(KSConfig.PUSH_ACTION.LOCAL_WEEKLY_PERFORMANCE, notification)
}

companion object {
    val channelId = MyFMessagingService.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID + KSConfig.PUSH_ACTION.LOCAL_WEEKLY_PERFORMANCE
}

}
```